# rviz does not run on virtual machine - Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit on VirtualBox. I just installed the rviz and tried to run it using "rosrun rviz rviz" command. But the followings will be shown and it doesn't start.
How can I fix the issue?

```
[ INFO] [1395806079.738572838]: rviz version 1.10.11
[ INFO] [1395806079.739463083]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1395806080.677327493]: OpenGl version: 2.1 (GLSL 1.2).
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I may note that I enabled 3D acceleration before turning on the virtual machine, but the system details there is no sign of having a 128 MB graphics card.
Also, I executed the following code, but rviz does not run yet:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144391/rviz-does-not-run-on-virtual-machine---illegal-instruction-(core-dumped)/) by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-25**:
Do other opengl applications work? Try apt-getting mesa-utils and running glxgears to make sure that a simple opengl application works.

**Comment by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on 2014-03-26**:
No it doesn't run ...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
What should I do? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys, I solved the issue partially.

The problem was stemming from lack of 3D support in the Ubuntu installed as virtual machine.

Now, when I execute the command "glxgears" it runs having no problem. But when I execute the command

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

it shows a segmentation fault. How should I resolve this issue?

---

Originally posted by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) with karma: 61 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-26**:
Do you have anything odd in your rviz config file? If not, you may have to resort to running rviz in gdb, getting a backtrace, and filing a bug here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz

**Comment by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on 2014-03-27**:
No, I haven't touched the rviz config file. I actually don't know where it is. I'm confused now. I need to work with rviz but I don't know how to ... .
The link you provided doesn't work.

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-27**:
answer.ros.org seems to append characters to the link :-( Copy/paste it manually: "https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Illegal instruction` errors pop up when you try to run a binary compiled to use instructions that your CPU does not have (ie: trying to use SSE4 when you only have SSE3). I've never seen using a VM cause those kind of errors.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on 2014-03-26**:
How can I use SSE4 instead of SSE3?
I may note that when I execute the rosrun rviz rviz command, rviz window opens up partially, but it doesn't show anything and closes suddenly.

**Comment by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on 2014-03-26**:
Also, when I execute the command glxgears it shows me the same error message "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"